Understanding proof of existence theorem of global class field theory more step by step ( Neukirch, Algebraic number theory VI - (6.1) theorem )
I am reading the Neukirch, Algebraic number theory, p.395, proof of (VI)- (6.1) theorem and stuck at some statements :
First, we equip the idele class group $C_K$ with its natural topology ( C.f. his book p.361 ).

(6.1) Theorem.  The map
$$ L \mapsto \mathcal{N}_L=N_{L|K}C_L $$
is a $1$-$1$ correspondence between the finite abelian extensions $L|K$ and the closed subgroups of finite index in $C_K$. Moreover one has :
$$ L_1 \subseteq L_2 \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{N}_{L_1} \supseteq \mathcal{N}_{L_2} , \ \mathcal{N}_{L_1 L_2} = \mathcal{N}_{L_1} \cap \mathcal{N}_{L_2}, \ \mathcal{N}_{L_1 \cap L_2}=\mathcal{N}_{L_1}\mathcal{N}_{L_2}.$$
The field $L|K$ corresponding to the subgroup $\mathcal{N}$ of $C_K$ is called the class field of $\mathcal{N}$. It satisfies $$ G(L|K) \cong C_K/\mathcal{N}.$$

Proof. By chap. IV. (6.7), all we have to show is that the subgroups $\mathcal{N}$ of $C_K$ which are open in the norm topology ( C.f. p.303 ) are precisely the closed subgroups of finite index for the natural topology.
If the subgroup $\mathcal{N}$ is open in the norm topology, then it contains a norm group $N_{L|K} C_L$ and is therefore of finite index, because from $(5.5)$, $ (C_K : N_{L|K} ) = \# G(L|K)^{\operatorname{ab}}$. To show that $\mathcal{N}$ is closed it is enough to show that $N_{L|K} C_L$ is. For this, we choose an infinite place $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$ and denote by $\Gamma_{K}$ the image of the subgroup of positive real numbers in $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ under the mapping $\langle \ \rangle : K_{\mathfrak{p}}^{*}\to C_K.$ Then $\Gamma_{K}$ is a group of representatives for the homomorphism $\mathfrak{N} : C_K \to \mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$ with kernel $C_K^{0}$ ( see section VI-1 ) ; i.e., $C_K = C_K^{0} \times \Gamma_K$.  By the same token, $\Gamma_K$ is a group of representatives for the homomorphism $\mathfrak{N} : C_L \to \mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$. WE therefore get
$$ N_{L|K}C_L = N_{L|K}C_L^{0} \times N_{L|K}\Gamma_{K} \stackrel{?}{=} N_{L|K}C_L^{0} \times \Gamma_{K}^{n} \stackrel{?}{=} N_{L|K}C_L^{0}\times \Gamma_K. \tag{1}$$
The norm map is continuous, and $C_L^{0}$ is compact by $(1.6)$. Hence $N_{L|K}C_L^{0}$ is closed. Since $\Gamma_K$ is clearly also cloed in $C_K$, we get that $N_{L|K} C_L$ is closed.
Conversely, ( Next proof is omitted.. )
I am now trying to understand the bold statemtns. First of all, what exactly is $\Gamma_K$ - what is the mapping $\langle \ \rangle : K_{\mathfrak{p}}^{*}\to C_K$?  Why $\Gamma_K$ is closed in $C_K$ and $C_K = C_K^{0} \times \Gamma_K$ ?
Second, why the equalities marked by question symbols in $(1)$ hold? I think that I am begginer of this domain - Algebraic number theory, class field theory etc.. - Can anyone help?
